# VBA code shows "Else without if error"

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to fix it but was not able to, although it's a very small code:
Please help, it's showing an "else without if" error:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Line2:
    Dim pass As String
    pass = InputBox("Enter Password")
    If pass = "hummer" Then GoTo Line1
    Else
    GoTo Line2
    End If

Line1:
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you used a `one liner IF statement`.
Try this:

```
    If pass = "hummer" Then 
        GoTo Line1
    Else
        GoTo Line2
    End If
```

There are 3 ways to contruct `IF` statement.
One is the `One Liner Construct` as I've mentioned above, which does not require to be terminated with `End If`.

**Example:**

```
If pass = "hummer" Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line2
```

Second is the `End If Terminated Construct`. Example of which is what I posted above.
Third one is the `If-EsleIf-Else End If terminated constuct` if you have multiple conditions.

**Example:**

```
If pass = "hummer" Then 
    GoTo Line1 
ElseIf pass = "something_else" Then
    GoTo Line2
Else
    GoTo Line3
End If
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more concisely and avoid using `GOTO` to control the flow of the program (which is generally a good idea) with a simple loop;

```
Dim pass As String

Do
    pass = InputBox("Enter Password")
    If pass = "hummer" Then Exit Do
Loop
```

Comment: Certainly the simplest way there is.